# Cast from double to int without truncating to zero

Tags: java, casting, integer, rgb, raytracing

I'm creating a Ray Tracer and I'm finding the ambient, diffuse, and specular intensity of my shapes(spheres). When I try to cast these values that are less than 1 to an integer value they get truncated back to zero.

```
int red = Color.getRed() * (int)totalIntensity;
        int green = Color.getGreen() * (int)totalIntensity;
        int blue = Color.getBlue() * (int)totalIntensity;
return new Color(red, green, blue);
```

The problem is that I need the values of red, green, and blue to be integers so I can return the new color. Is there anyway I can do this without turning all of the totalIntensity values to zero?

Comment: Cast after the multiplication? `(int)(Color.getRed() * totalIntensity)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that `int red = (int) (Color.getRed() * totalIntensity);` should do the job.

Comment: Please feel free to mark this as the approved answer :)